# Circle fitting with fixed radius using algorithm by Chernov

Tags: optimization, computational-geometry

I am doing a project where circle fitting is needed and I came across an algorithm and code found on the website (https://people.cas.uab.edu/~mosya/cl/CPPcircle.html) which works very well.

My question is, can I fix the radius of the circle that is going to be estimated? That means, I have some data that is acquired from a circle and I know the radius of the circle but not position of the center of it. I just need to estimate the center of the circle.

I read the paper by the authors Chernov and Lesort on circle fitting published in 2008 https://arxiv.org/pdf/cs/0301001.pdf and to my understanding, their algorithm incorprates both the center position and the radius into a parameter space and optimize them as a whole. I am wondering is there a way to just optimize the center position (x, y) of a circle whose radius is known?